# XMLHttpRequest cannot load when URL is with www

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented autosuggest script using jQuery on my website. When browser load my website with www ( i.e. `www.xyz.com` ) search suggestion doesn't works and prints the following error in browser console :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://xyz.com/json.php?json=true&limit=15&input=testing. Origin
>   http://www.xyz.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I know that jQuery / Chrome doesn't allows me to make cross domain AJAX call but when I access my website without www ( i.e. just `xyz.com`) everything works perfectly. How can I solve this problem ? Does any one has Idea about it ?

Answer (score 4):

You are violating the [same origin policy restriction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

`http://www.xyz.com` and `http://xyz.com` are considered cross domains according to this policy.

To solve the problem just use a relative url in your `$.ajax()` request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/json.php',
    ...
});
```

instead of absolute:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://xyz.com/json.php',
    ...
});
```

Comment: what if I am accessing with simple javascript ?

Comment: It's absolutely the same. You should use a relative url. What do you think that the `$.ajax()` method does at the end of the day? It uses simple javascript behind the scenes to instantiate the `XMLHttpRequest` object and pass it the url.

Comment: It didn't work for me :o ! I change to relative path. Still I am facing same error..

Comment: That's very strange. Could you show your code? Normally if you use a relative url you should never have such issues.

Comment: Can we continue this on GTALK? my ID is thakerhardiks@gmail.com ?

Comment: It would be much more helpful to anyone if you show your code here instead of having some private chats. This way your question might help other people having the same problem as well. So you could leave a comment once you have posted your code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23843/discussion-between-hardik-thaker-and-darin-dimitrov)